# Unable to dinamically create objects from MongoDB results in Python 3.5.2

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, class, oop, instance

I'm pretty new to Python even though I have some OOP experience from working with PHP in the past.

I'm trying to create a module that will query mongoDB and create objects in a dictionary for every document it gets back from the db. The documents data will generate entries in the object's attributes dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from django.db import models
from pymongo import MongoClient

# abstract Class() blueprint
class Clase():
    attributes = {}

mongodb_connection = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
bi_db = mongodb_connection['bi']
sales_collection = bi_db['sales_data_it']
documents = sales_collection.find( {} )
print ('Documents: %d' % documents.count())

# Create instances from mongoDB documents
instance_dict = {}
i = 0
for result in documents:
    print('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
    print('creating instance[%d]' % i)  
    instance_dict[i] = Clase()  # create an object in instance_dict for each result

    for key, value in result.items() : # for every result log key,values into attributes dictionary
        print(result)
        instance_dict[i].attributes[key] = value
        print(key, ' = ', value, i)
    i += 1

# print ('Instances Created: %d' % len(instance_dict.keys()))
print('-------------INSTANCE 0--------------------')
print(instance_dict[0].attributes)
print('-------------INSTANCE 1--------------------')
print(instance_dict[1].attributes)
```

My test database contains only 2 documents and the logic appears to work when debugging this code using the print() function. However, when reading the created objects attributes I see that they both contain the data for the second document instead of each containing the data for their respective document. Not sure if that made sense. Here's the output from my terminal when running this script:

```
root@django:~/Desktop/scripts# ./test.py 
Documents: 2
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
creating instance[0]
Members  =  ['Marco Ravaglia', 'Mattia Castelluccia', 'Alberto Ballerini'] 0
_id  =  58d8e4492b9afb1045503665 0
Performance  =  0.85 0
Team Name  =  NCA-Milan 0
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
creating instance[1]
Team Leader  =  Isidoro De Pascale 1
Members  =  ['Marinka Piacente', 'Luca Lo Monaco', 'Matteo Ferri'] 1
_id  =  58d8e4492b9afb1045503666 1
Team Name  =  NCA-Napoli 1
-------------INSTANCE 0--------------------
{'Team Leader': 'Isidoro De Pascale', 'Members': ['Marinka Piacente', 'Luca Lo Monaco', 'Matteo Ferri'], '_id': ObjectId('58d8e4492b9afb1045503666'), 'Performance': '0.85', 'Team Name': 'NCA-Napoli'}
-------------INSTANCE 1--------------------
{'Team Leader': 'Isidoro De Pascale', 'Members': ['Marinka Piacente', 'Luca Lo Monaco', 'Matteo Ferri'], '_id': ObjectId('58d8e4492b9afb1045503666'), 'Performance': '0.85', 'Team Name': 'NCA-Napoli'}
```

As you can see both instances contain the same data. I dont understand why...
Sorry if this has been asked before but I've looked for an answer to this problem without success. I've also made my best to debug the problem but I just can't get to the bottom of it. I'm going crazy so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was setting the attributes dict as a 'Class' variable instead of an 'Instance' variable. Therefore they were being overwritten by each object iteration.

I solved this by creating getter and setter methods that will deal with this variables on a per instance basis. Note that I decided to mangle the variables dict even though I read somewhere that this is not the "Python way" of doing things. I had to throw in a generator method to yield the contents of the variables_dict when needed as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from pymongo import MongoClient

def get_mongoDb_collection(conn, db, col):
    mongodb_connection = MongoClient(conn)
    database = mongodb_connection[db]
    collection = database[col]
    return collection

class Clase:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__variables = kwargs

    def set_variable(self, k, v):
        self.__variables[k] = v

    def get_variable(self, k):
        # return self.__variables[k] # raises KeyError exception if key doesn't exist, the get() method below returns None
        return self.__variables.get(k, '"{}" variable NOT Found'.format(k)) # returns None if default value NOT specified

    def get_all_variables(self):
        for k,v in self.__variables.items():
            yield k,v

def main():    
    sales_collection = get_mongoDb_collection('mongodb://localhost:27017/', 'bi', 'sales_data_it')
    documents = sales_collection.find( {} )
    print ('Found Documents: {}'.format(documents.count()))

    instance_dict = {}
    i = 0
    for result in documents:
        print('+++++++++++++++++++ Creating instance[{}] +++++++++++++++++++'.format(i))
        # print(result)
        instance_dict[i] = Clase()  # create an object in instance_dict for each result
        for key, value in result.items() : # for every result log key,values into variables dictionary
            print(' {}= {}'.format(key, value))
            instance_dict[i].set_variable(key, value)
        i += 1

    print('------------------- Inspecting created instances -------------------')
    for key, instance in instance_dict.items():
        print(' ... Instance {} ...'.format(key))
        for key, value in instance.get_all_variables():
            print(' {}= {}'.format(key,value))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Running this script now returns the expected objects with the correct data:

```
Found Documents: 2
+++++++++++++++++++ Creating instance[0] +++++++++++++++++++
    _id= 58d8e4492b9afb1045503665
    Team Name= NCA-Milan
    Performance= 0.85
    Members= ['Marco Ravaglia', 'Mattia Castelluccia', 'Alberto Ballerini']
+++++++++++++++++++ Creating instance[1] +++++++++++++++++++
    Team Leader= Isidoro De Pascale
    _id= 58d8e4492b9afb1045503666
    Team Name= NCA-Napoli
    Members= ['Marinka Piacente', 'Luca Lo Monaco', 'Matteo Ferri']
------------------- Inspecting created instances -------------------
    ... Instance 0 ...
    Members= ['Marco Ravaglia', 'Mattia Castelluccia', 'Alberto Ballerini']
    _id= 58d8e4492b9afb1045503665
    Team Name= NCA-Milan
    Performance= 0.85
    ... Instance 1 ...
    Members= ['Marinka Piacente', 'Luca Lo Monaco', 'Matteo Ferri']
    _id= 58d8e4492b9afb1045503666
    Team Leader= Isidoro De Pascale
    Team Name= NCA-Napoli
```

I still thought to share the answer to my problem in case it may be useful to someone else in the future but rememember that if you really want something done you better do it yourself. Thanks for everything Stack Overflow, or whatever!